# A non-normal linear operator can have eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

May I say that only normal linear operators have eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: no.............

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: I was not sure if eigenvalues only ocurr in matrices diagonalized by unitary matrices (Spectral Decomposition Theorem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The operator $T\colon\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $T(x,y)=(x+y,y)$ is not normal, but $(1,0)$ is an eigenvector and $1$ is an eigenvalue.

Answer (score 2):

In finite dimension, finding the eigenvalues is equivalent to find the roots of the characteristic polynomial of the operator. So *every* operator on $\mathbb{C}^n$ and *every* operator on $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ has at least one eigenvalue (and, consequently, at least one eigenvector).

Comment: In real spaces, why only in odd dimensions?

Comment: Every real polynomial of odd degree has at least one real root. This is not true in the case of even degree, where there are polynomials without real roots (for instance, $x^2+1$).

Comment: Indeed Francesco! Thanks.